# Blender Guru Anvil Tutorial Base Problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, geometry, subdivision-surface

[image: Blender Anvil Base Problem]

Ok, so I followed the tutorial pretty much to the letter. I was near the end of video 2. I deleted the bottom face and extruded it together with Clipping and Merge like he showed, then proceeded to put in the other missing faces on the left and right of the base as oriented in this photo. When I showed the Sub Surf Modifier, I got this instead of it being completely smooth, you can see the weird flat part at the bottom. I'm not sure how to fix it.

One note, I did have an older version of Blender, 4.6x. I just recently updated it to 4.79 yesterday. I just tried to fix the bottom and I still get this problem. Please help.

Edit: Ok so here is the Blender Guru's Anvil Mesh...
[image: Blender Guru's Anvil Mesh]

Then here is my Anvil Mesh...[image: My Anvil Mesh]
So there's that.

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'm uploading it now thru the blend-exchange link you left.

Comment: Here's the .blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5390" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5390/)

Answer (score 4):

You have several vertices overlapping, you can merge them quickly with <kbd>A</kbd> (Select All), then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* (previously <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*).

[image]

Comment: I was sure I did that. *facepalm* They say, sometimes the solution is the simplest thing you can think of. *sigh* Thank you. Have yourself a wonderful day!